# Stop propagation of recursive function conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a pathfinding application, where I have created a grid of size 30*60, there is a starting element from where we have to start the path searching and a ending element where we have to stop the function once we reach the ending, in between I have marked all grids as visited. Also have created a variable named `stopVisiting`, so that once we reach the destination we will set `stopVisiting` to `true` to stop the function. But it is not working,

Code:

```
const [stopVisiting, setStopVisiting] = useState(false);
  const startVisiting = (visElement) => {
    if (visElement.i === endElement.i && visElement.j === endElement.j) {
      setStopVisiting(true);
    }
    if (visElement.wall === true) return;
    if (stopVisiting === true) {
      console.log("Stop the function here");
      return;
    } else {
      if (visElement["visited"] === false) {
        var newGrid = [...grid];
        newGrid[visElement.i][visElement.j]["visited"] = true;
        setGrid(newGrid);
        visElement["visited"] = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (visElement["i"] > 0) {
            startVisiting(grid[visElement.i - 1][visElement.j]);
          }
          if (visElement["i"] < 39) {
            startVisiting(grid[visElement.i + 1][visElement.j]);
          }
          if (visElement["j"] > 0) {
            startVisiting(grid[visElement.i][visElement.j - 1]);
          }
          if (visElement["j"] < 59) {
            startVisiting(grid[visElement.i][visElement.j + 1]);
          }
          return;
        }, 500);
      }
    }
  };
```

It is actually logging the statement `Stop the function here`, but it not working.

`wall` element is the blocked space, through which we cannot pass.

Comment: React states are updating asynchronously, so it is likely that the recursion is blocking the state from being updated because React thinks there's still more operations to do and therefore queues the update. Does `stopVisiting` have to be a state? Can it be a ref instead? If it is not used in the render function, consider changing it to a ref.

Comment: @Terry, Yes it worked, I didn't knew about this concept, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you call `setStopVisiting(true)`, your `stopVisiting` is not getting assigned a new value so `stopVisiting === true` is never going to be true.

Instead, don't use a `stopVisiting` state... it is not needed. You can know whether you have reached the end by making sure you mark it as visited and then by checking `endElement.visited`, which really is the equivalent of what you intended with `stopVisiting`.

#### Some other remarks

- It is not needed to do both of the following, since they achieve the same:

  ```
  newGrid[visElement.i][visElement.j]["visited"] = true;
  visElement["visited"] = true;
  ```

  These two assignments assign to the `visited` property of the *same* object (Note that `newGrid` is a shallow copy of `grid`, so its objects are not copies, but that's OK).
- The notations `["visited"]` and `.visited` achieve the same. I'd stick with the latter.
- You have several conditions that stop the process from visiting an element:

  - Having reached the target element
  - Hitting a wall
  - Encountering an element that was already visited.

  These three cases can be checked in one and the same `if` statement

Here is the updated code:

```
  const startVisiting = (visElement) => {
    if (visElement.wall || visElement.visited || endElement.visited) return;

    visElement.visited = true; // This will eventually set `endElement.visited`
    setGrid([...grid]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const {i, j} = visElement;  // Destructure to make code below more readable
      if (i >  0) startVisiting(grid[i - 1][j]);
      if (i < 39) startVisiting(grid[i + 1][j]);
      if (j >  0) startVisiting(grid[i][j - 1]);
      if (j < 59) startVisiting(grid[i][j + 1]);
    }, 500);
  };
```

Comment: This really helped me, now the function looks optimized and highly readable, thank you, btw can you hint me something more, as now I have to store the path in an array, so it means we have to store the valid visitedElements. Any hint/suggestion how to do that.?